# How to set text gradient

Tags: css, text, gradient

Hello i got problem with text gradient

```
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#0689b6, #10ace3, #0689b6);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```

This code works fine except the IE and Moziila ... Any advice how fixed this ? Gratefull for any solution.

Comment: All I can see is `-webkit` that's why.

Answer (score 2):

it will work on all browsers

```css
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#0689b6, #10ace3, #0689b6);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
        // for firefox
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#0689b6, #10ace3, #0689b6);
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
          // for opera
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#0689b6, #10ace3, #0689b6);
    -o-background-clip: text;
    -o-text-fill-color: transparent;
        //for i.E
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#0689b6, #10ace3, #0689b6);
    -ms-background-clip: text;
    -ms-text-fill-color: transparent;
           // for other
     background: linear-gradient(#0689b6, #10ace3, #0689b6);
     background-clip: text;
     text-fill-color: transparent;
```

Comment: Thanks for help Bilal Maqsood ... But it wont work still in IE and Mozzila

Comment: Still not but thanks much x) ... its very strange i think that´s the right way but IE and Mozzila not share the same opinion:D grrr damn

Comment: apply style like `p{ style goes here }` or `h1{ }` i dont know how you are adding these styles

Comment: Background-clip: text is **only** supported by webkit browsers.